store in configuration or not
What is the Best Location for connection string in the Program.cs or Appsetting.json and i want To know about  the hard codding more ..
Well I put the connection string in the appsetting.json and program.cs too and its better to be in the appsetting.json because its more flexible to go to staging mode and developing mode

Connection strings should not be hard-coded and are usually added to appsettings.json as they can easily be changed. I say usually because there are other places that can be used to keep such details out of source control such as in a secrets file, environment variablesetc.


What is the Best Location for connection string in the Program.cs or Appsetting.json

The question should be "store in configuration or not". And the answer is - use configuration (unless it is small "one time" app).
Note that appsettings.json is not the only potential source of the config (I highly recommend to read the previous link carefully), for example if you have sensitive data in the connection string/settings then for development environment you can use the Secret Manager. Or environment variables (which is quite popular option for production environments)
